# Custom dns resolver isn't specific to Domain

Tags: dns, aws, systemd-resolved

I have a custom DNS resolver, similar to how Consul provides DNS. They have you set [systemd-resolved like so](https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/tutorials/networking/dns-forwarding#systemd-resolved-setup).

```
# File /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/consul.conf
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1:8600
DNSSEC=false
Domains=~consul
```

It sounds like this should only go to this DNS resolver (listening on port 8600) for domains ending in `.consul`. However, using this setup myself and some code (not Consul) and logging when it gets queries, I can see that all DNS queries (e.g `dig example.com`) ends being sent to that program!

**I'm not sure what I'm missing to only handle queries for a specific domain.** Here are relevant files:

**/etc/resolv.conf** (yep, aws EC2 servers):

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search us-east-2.compute.internal
```

**File /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/service.conf**

```
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1:8600
DNSSEC=false
Domains=~service
```

Output of `resolvectl` commands:

(Yes, I'm using `.service` instead of `.consul`).

```
#$ resolvectl status

Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub
Current DNS Server: 127.0.0.1:8600
       DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1:8600
        DNS Domain: ~service

Link 2 (ens5)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 10.0.0.2
       DNS Servers: 10.0.0.2
        DNS Domain: us-east-2.compute.internal
```

Do I perhaps need to create another `[Resolve]` section for `Domains=~.` ? And perhaps point that to the default gateway (`10.0.0.2` in my case or something like `8.8.8.8`).

Ideally I can keep using these ec2 instances default DNS setting and "hook" into it, but perhaps I need to blow it up.